# iOS- Constraint errors when switching multiple TextFields

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, snapkit

I have a standard TableViewController and set it to a fixed value: 55 in the `heightForRowAt` function.
Each row has a UILabel and a UITextField. Here's my layout, and I'm using SnapKit.

```
contentView.addSubview(label)
contentView.addSubview(textField)

label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
  make.left.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
  make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
}
label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

textField.snp.makeConstraints { make in
  make.right.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
  make.centerY.equalTo(label)
  make.left.equalTo(label.snp.right).offset(8)
}
```

In this custom cell, I wrote a delegate to respond when the keyboard touch return, the TableViewController will make the textField become the first responder at the next cell. Here's the delegate function:

```
func cellShouldResignFirstResponder(_ cell: PITextFieldTableCell) -> Bool {
guard
  let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell),
  let index = textFieldCellIndexPaths.firstIndex(of: indexPath)
  else { return false }


let nextIndex = index + 1
if nextIndex < textFieldCellIndexPaths.endIndex {
  let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: textFieldCellIndexPaths[nextIndex]) as? PITextFieldTableCell
  cell?.becomeFirstResponder()
} else {
  tableView.scrollToRow(at: textFieldCellIndexPaths[0], at: .top, animated: true)
  tableView.endEditing(true)
}

return true
```

}

```
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2838f7480 'assistantHeight' TUISystemInputAssistantView:0x101842d90.height == 55   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2838f9bd0 'assistantView.bottom' TUISystemInputAssistantView:0x101842d90.bottom == _UIKBCompatInputView:0x11011d540.top   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2838f9b80 'assistantView.top' V:|-(0)-[TUISystemInputAssistantView:0x101842d90]   (active, names: '|':UIInputSetHostView:0x1019a4ba0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2838f3200 'inputView.top' V:|-(0)-[_UIKBCompatInputView:0x11011d540]   (active, names: '|':UIInputSetHostView:0x1019a4ba0 )>"
)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2838f9bd0 'assistantView.bottom' TUISystemInputAssistantView:0x101842d90.bottom == _UIKBCompatInputView:0x11011d540.top   (active)>
```

This report will appear only when I touch the return for the first time. I have looked up lots of similar cases, it makes me think that it is a bug from Apple. but, it's just my guess. :)

Comment: However, when I click on the first Textfield in the tableView, I jump to the next cell by pressing the return button of the keyboard successfully. but, the console print a report for constraint error.

Comment: This is an ***internal*** `UIKit` constraints error. The `TUISystemInputAssistantView` is part of the built-in keyboard. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @DonMag Oops, indeed. I didn't pay attention to this part. Thanks for your comment!